# BIDS (SQL Server 2008 R2) integration with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, version, bids

We are working on a data warehouse project using SQL Server 2008 R2 and it's related BI tools (Entity Data Model, DLL, SSIS, SSAS, SSRS). Soon my team is going to need source control. We have Visual Studio 2012 set up. When we open project files in Visual Studio 2012 to check them in, they are updated from Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008 format to 2012 format and no longer run correctly against our 2008 environment.

Has anyone had any issues like this? Does anyone have a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TFS, you could use [Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16338), which will add the TFS plug-ins you need (Source Control Explorer) to check in your items. You could also use TFS Power Tools to check in items from Windows Explorer.

Comment: Yes, we are using TFS 2012. The issue is not when we check in, the issue is that after the files are converted to the 2012 format they are no longer compatible with the local 2008 environment.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2008 R2, you will need to continue developing in BIDS 2008. VS 2012 SSDT and higher will automatically convert your files.

Comment: Does that mean that I cannot incorporate VS source control for team sharing?

Comment: You can use VS Source Control, but will need to do so through the VS 2008 Team Explorer shell (linked in my original comment).